# Create a page to redirect to a different page for my session based on usertype but only the second header location is redirecting

Tags: php, mysql

Create a page to redirect to a different page for my session based on user type but only the second header location is redirecting.

```
<?php

include_once 'config.php';

if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $error = '';

    if (empty($email) || empty($password)) {
        $error = '<p class="error">Invaid email or password.</p>';
    } elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error = '<p class="error">Invaid email or password.</p>';
    } else {
        $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);

        $stmt->execute();

        /* fetch value */
        $res = $stmt->get_result();

        if ($user = $res->fetch_object()) {
            if (password_verify($password, $user->password)) {
                //login is true
                $_SESSION['user'] = [
                    'uid' => $user->id,
                    'email' => $user->email

                ];

                $_SESSION['login'] = true;

                if ($user_type == "1") { //check usertype

                    header("Location:dashboard.php");
                } else {
                    header("Location:dashboard_usr.php");
                }
            }
        } else {
            $error = '<p style="color:         #ea2b1f">Ooops! Invaid email or password.</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Always `exit` after `header("Location: ...")`

Comment: have you checked if that condition is being met? just `echo` 'test' and then exit to see if that condition is being met where the first redirect is.

Comment: @MattFryer still no luck not working

Comment: @MattFryer I get undefined variable

Comment: If `$user_type` is undefined then you need to ensure you are assigning it something (in this case `"1"`) somewhere...

Comment: @MattFryer I defined using 'usertype' => $user->user_type and assigned but still keep getting undefined

Comment: Is `$user->user_type` used in the if statement? At the moment you are using `$user_type`.

Comment: if($user_type == "1") that is what amusing @MattFryer

Comment: Then you need to change this to `if ($user->user_type == "1")` if that is what you are using

Comment: @MattFryer thanks...it is working prolly you want post the answer

Comment: I've upvoted @msphn's answer and posted an answer myself : )

Comment: @MattFryer that is fine...I did that also but unfortunately I dont have reputation yet to do that

Comment: Side note: Best to add `exit;` after each header. Otherwise, your code might want to continue to execute.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner well spotted! I must be tired...

Comment: *welcome guys*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($user_type == "1") {
```

`$user_type` is not declared within your code. You certainly want write something like `$user->type` or `$user->user_type` or however it's called in your database!

Comment: Is it declared? At the moment it's not possible to know if it's declared previously or not.

Comment: As I said, it's not declared. I posted the solution, if he tries it, it will work. He should even get a notice / warning at the moment.

Comment: I don't think so :-).

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that this should be a question in the comments rather than an answer at this stage but no worries : )

Comment: He only got another file called config. It's pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Well, I disagree. It is certainly unclear where the user type is stored, but @msphn made a very good observation which might be the answer. With the limit knowledge of OP's code this is the best answer we have.

Comment: It's not self-explanatory at all, you're making assumptions, but if you think you should jump straight to an answer before checking with the OP then no worries

Comment: I would have asked in a comment, but I'm unable to comment due to restrictions. The only best thing I could do, was to write an answer.

Comment: Oh, ok, I didn't know that : )

Comment: Actually I'm trying to gather reputation and sharing my know-how .. just not as easy as excepted.

Comment: Nothing I have said was intended to be discouraging, there's no tone in text, it's just a discussion, keep up the good work : )

Comment: @msphn If this answers correct I'll give it an upvote : ) I think it probably will be after discussing the question with the OP

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are assigning a value to the variable used in the if statement beforehand. I'd also recommend you check for equality using the identical operator `===` whenever possible and to use integers instead of strings in situations like this where you are representing a category with a number. As @FunkFortyNiner added, you should always exit after a redirect. Summarised like this:

```
$user->user_type = 1;
if ($user->user_type === 1)
{
    header("Location: dashboard.php");
    exit();
}
```